# Change properties of application pool

Tags: c#, iis-7, application-pool

Is there any way to make this code more nicer ?

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
            ApplicationPoolCollection applicationPoolCollection = serverManager.ApplicationPools;

            foreach (var site in serverManager.Sites)
            {

                //Trace.WriteLine("Site: {0}", site.Name);)
                foreach (var app in site.Applications)
                {

                    if (app.Path.EndsWith("Report") || app.Path.EndsWith("Data"))
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("ReportApi     "  + app.ApplicationPoolName);

                        applicationPoolCollection[app.ApplicationPoolName].Enable32BitAppOnWin64 = true;
                        applicationPoolCollection[app.ApplicationPoolName].ManagedRuntimeVersion = "v4.0";


                    }
                }
            }

            serverManager.CommitChanges();
```

Second question , what will happen if I will run it on PC that has only iis6

Thanks for help.

Comment: What's wrong with code as is? "Nice" is not very precise concept - the code looks pretty clear as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks pretty tidy to me. If you want to flatten things a bit, you can <strike>use the `Cast` extension method (which operates on types of `IEnumerable` to convert them to `IEnumerable<T>`) to</strike> make things more LINQy. It makes things clearer to some, more opaque to others. Take your pick.

```
var reportOrDataApps = serverManager
    .Sites
    .Cast<Site>()
    .SelectMany(s => s.Applications.Cast<Application>())
    .Where(app => app.Path.EndsWith("Report") || app.Path.EndsWith("Data"))

foreach(var app in reportOrDataApps)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("ReportApi     "  + app.ApplicationPoolName);
    applicationPoolCollection[app.ApplicationPoolName].Enable32BitAppOnWin64 = true;
    applicationPoolCollection[app.ApplicationPoolName].ManagedRuntimeVersion = "v4.0";
}
```

EDIT:

It appears that the collections already implement `IEnumerable<T>` so you can shorten the LINQ:

```
var reportOrDataApps = serverManager
    .Sites
    .SelectMany(s => s.Applications)
    .Where(app => app.Path.EndsWith("Report") || app.Path.EndsWith("Data"))
```

Comment: +1 for sample... Note one should target code to people who will be reading it - if you/your team is not proficient with LINQ than nested select may easily hide what actually happens (unlike 2 foreach).

Comment: I find that stating such problems in LINQ usually leads to more correct code (less nesting, less complexity). Definitely worth picking up if you haven't already.